# How do I force a process to break when debugging if I don't know where to place the breakpoint?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

How do I force an asp.net app to break in VS 2008 when I don't know what code the process is hitting?  I am getting a problem where there seems to be something looping in the code and after putting in a bazillion breakpoints in can't find it.  I want to force the app to break so that I can see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break it by pressing the pause (Break All) "||" button in the debug toolbar.